# threejs: GLTF Model and Textures loaded, but model not showing up

Tags: javascript, three.js, gltf

I learned how to use three.js, but now im stuck. I uploaded my model to the server, and it gets loaded fine, but it won't show up in the three.js window. I added a light and the model, and in the developer tools of the browser it shows that all files are loaded.

Can anyone help me?

Javascript:

```
import * as THREE from 'three';
import { GLTFLoader } from '../node_modules/three/examples/jsm/loaders/GLTFLoader.js';

const scene = new THREE.Scene();

const camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera( 75, window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight, 0.1, 1000 );
camera.position.z = 2.5;

const renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer( {
    canvas: eddie
});
renderer.setSize( 500, 500 );
document.body.appendChild( renderer.domElement );

const color = 0x11111;
const intensity = 1;
const light = new THREE.AmbientLight(color, intensity);
scene.add(light);

const loader = new GLTFLoader();

loader.load( './models/eddieFinal.gltf', function ( gltf ) {
    let eddie = scene.add( gltf.scene );
    eddie.scale.set(1, 1, 1);
    eddie.position.set()
    console.log(eddie.position);
    renderer.render(scene, camera);
}, undefined, function ( error ) {
    console.error( error );
} );
```

Searched on google, but found nothing. Moved around the camera with no sucess.

Answer (score 0):

Got it, changed the size to 0.1 and then I saw it.